# Newbie trying to install Python, Setting Path, zsh: Permission denied

Tags: python, linker

I'm taking a class on Coursera, this is what it's asking me to do.

> `brew info python`
>
> The section you are interested in is the location of where it was
> installed.
>
> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
> installed into   `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin`
>
> The `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.x/libexec/bin` is the one you want to
> use and set for your path. Copy it from the terminal. Depending on the
> version of Mac OS you are running the next steps may vary slightly.

When I enter in: `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin`

I get this:

```
zsh: permission denied: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to execute `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin` as an actual command.  It's a directory.

You're supposed to add it to your PATH environment variable, so that you can run the commands contained in that directory.

Add this line to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
typeset -x PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks. It says "zsh: no such file or directory:"

Comment: @lnewb I have no idea what that error message is from.  What command did you type?

Comment: I'm at 

"6. Run the following: 

Zsh shell source ~/.zshrc and when I run it it says "zsh: command not found: shell"

Comment: I don't think it literally meant "shell" as part of the command.  Try this: `source ~/.zshrc`